# How to put the video title in html?

Tags: html, video

I have a video in html (the format is webm) and it works but, I want to appear the video title in the html (without writing it).

PS: To put the video, I used Media Element.

Comment: Pick a programming language, read the meta data embedded in the video, generate the HTML using that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/). You should read `attributes of html element` to get title of your video. To do that, read more about it [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml). You can also try to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and it's method called [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: isn't there some tutorial about that?