# How to add video title in html Video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to show the video title at the top of the video in HTML, like in Youtube when we play video in the fullscreen video title display above.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

@Akif Malik: you can get help from this links as it is related to your question

[Add text above HTML5 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422105/add-text-above-html5-video/10422374)

[How to put the video title in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005882/how-to-put-the-video-title-in-html)

Comment: @Akif Malik: show your efforts what you  code so  that you can  achieve your result

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I want to show the title at the top of the video when it is playing in fullscreen, as in Youtube when a video is playing in fullscreen mode title of the video is displaying above.

Comment: Perfect answer to me. Thank you @AsiyaFatima